# What do the arguments for TFRecordOptions actually mean (wrt tf.io.TFRecordWriter)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tfrecord

I export some fairly large Pandas dataframes to Tensorflow's serialized format. And I do it often and it's really slow. Which is probably because I have to serialize the individual examples idk. Also, I compress the files with the "GZIP" option.

I have found some options for the TFRecordWriter in the documentation that look like they might help (buffers help, right?).
But there is no explanation of what `input_buffer_size` does or what range the values might take. Is it {0, 1, 2, 3} or a couple of million? Or do I want `output_buffer_size` or `mem_level` or something else?

From the [Tensorflow 2.5 documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/TFRecordOptions):

```
Args
compression_type        "GZIP", "ZLIB", or "" (no compression).
flush_mode              flush mode or None, Default: Z_NO_FLUSH.
input_buffer_size       int or None.
output_buffer_size      int or None.
window_bits             int or None.
compression_level       0 to 9, or None.
compression_method      compression method or None.
mem_level               1 to 9, or None.
compression_strategy    strategy or None. Default: Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY.
```

Comment: I've searched GitHub and found both `input_buffer_size=16777216, output_buffer_size=104857600` and `input_buffer_size=100, output_buffer_size=100` which I guess narrows down my search space but I still don't know what these parameters do.

Comment: It looks like using the big numbers made it 30% faster. I guess that's worth something.

Comment: Any updates on that?, I am trying to write some tfrecord files but the process is too slow, any ideas on how to buffer the serializing process?

Comment: I think it might just be slow. Currently I'm looking at https://github.com/webdataset since it seems optimized for fast reads at least. And it can do the write/read for both TF and PyTorch so I figure it might be more flexible. It was originally an NVIDIA project but seems to have it's own repository now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some description is given in [tf_record.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a4dfb8d1a71385bd6d122e4f27f86dcebb96712d/tensorflow/python/lib/io/tf_record.py#L65).  That will point to the zlib library which gives some more complete information.

Sadly, the text is in the `__init__()` method so don't seem to appear in the Tensorflow autodocs

I won't post an "answer" as reading the comments is easy once you find the link and they will remain more accurate than anything I would write.

As a small note, the default for the *_buffer_size is 25,600.